# object returned from webservice call gets mangle with additional bytes in my conversion function

Tags: c#, .net, xml, web-services, linq-to-xml

Concise...object returned from webservice call gets mangle with additional bytes in my conversion function.

Basically I have a webreference that I send an XDocument to

```
    System.Text.ASCIIEncoding encoding = new System.Text.ASCIIEncoding();
    Byte[] baXml = encoding.GetBytes(xdoc.ToString());

    object o = MEF_Test.NewSubmission("*********", "*********", baXml);
```

The transmission is successful and I get back what I assume is the xml document and I am trying to go back to an XDocument. I convert my object to a byte array

```
    Byte[] baResponse = ObjectToByteArray(o);
```

I put this function in at the bottom but it may be where there error is at

The object I get back is 10492 characters but gets bigger by 28 bytes to the size of 10520 after conversion

```
            string ss = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(baResponse);
            string ss1 = ss.Substring(28);
            XDocument xSubmissionResponse = XDocument.Parse(ss1);
```

In the screenshot you can see the extra characters and I attempt to get past them by getting the substring past them.  The string then looks good but then throws an exception about a hexadecimal value 0x0B further ahead in the string.

Can anyone give this a look?  Thanks.

--[Screenshot with as much info as possible](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wQMQG.png)

I don't have the reputation to stick the image in I hope the link works.

```
    private static byte[] ObjectToByteArray(Object obj)
    {
       if (obj == null)
          return null;
       BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
       MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
       bf.Serialize(ms, obj);
       return ms.ToArray();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

o is already an array of bytes (as seen in the debugger). Deserializing it again makes no sense. Just cast object o to byte[] and then run the Encoding.GetString method on it.

Comment: This worked...thanks.  I don't have the rep to upvote or I would.